# c++ iterate through all neighbor permutations

Tags: c++, permutation

I have a vector of N objects, and I would like to iterate through all neighbor permutations of this vector. What I call a neighbor permutation is a permutation where only two elements of the original vector would be changed : 
if I have a vector with `'a','b','c','d'` then :

```
'b','a','c','d' //is good
'a','c','b','d' //is good
'b','a','d','c' //is not good (2 permutations)
```

If I use `std::next_permutation(myVector.begin(), myVector.end()` then I will get all the possible permutations, not only the "neighbor" ones...

Do you have any idea how that could be achieved ?

Comment: Look at it as a binary value, where each entry is a bit, then read about [gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).

Comment: [std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/)?

Comment: The usual mathematical term for those "neighbor permutations" is transpositions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Transpositions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, I thought I would filter the permutations that have a [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) greater than 2.

However, if you really only need to generate all the vectors resulting by swapping one pair, it would be more efficient if you do like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        // swap i and j
```

Depending on whether you need to collect all the results or not, you should make a copy or the vector before the swap, or swap again i and j after you processed the current permutation.

Collect all the results:

```
std::vector< std::vector<T> > neighbor_permutations;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        std::vector<T> perm(v);
        std::swap(perm[i], perm[j]);
        neighbor_permutations.push_back(perm);
    }
}
```

Faster version - do not collect results:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        std::swap(v[i], v[j]);
        process_permutation(v);
        std::swap(v[i], v[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually the idea is to avoid going through all the existing permutation (40320 for only 8 elements...) but just the ones I need (28 for 8 elements)

Comment: Sorry, but if you're suggesting iterating over all permutations, then pruning these, then the overhead is HUGE!

Comment: much better with your edit :).. But same remark as the other answer : as I understand, if I use `std::swap` it would actually modify my vector so I would each time have the neighbor of the previous vector and not of the original one.. so should I unswap the element each time ?

Comment: that depends if you need to collect all the results or not. if yes, then copy the vector, swap i and j, and store it somewhere. if not, just swap i and j again after you have finished working on the current permutation

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's a good idea to divide this into two parts:

- How to generate the "neighbor permutations"
- How to iterate over them

---

Regarding the first, it's easy to write a function:

```
std::vector<T> make_neighbor_permutation(
    const std::vector<T> &orig, std::size_t i, std::size_t j);
```

which swaps *i* and *j*. I did not understand from your question if there's an additional constraint that *j = i + 1*, in which case you could drop a parameter.

---

Armed with this function, you now need an iterator that iterates over all legal combinations of *i* and *j* (again, I'm not sure of the interpretation of your question. It might be that there are *n - 1* values).

This is very easy to do using [`boost::iterator_facade`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html). You simply need to define an iterator that takes in the constructor your original iterator, and sets *i* (and possibly *j*) to initial values. As it is incremented, it needs to update the index (or indices). The dereference method needs to call the above function.

Comment: It seems quite nice. But as I understand, if I use `std::swap` it would actually modify my vector so I would each time have the neighbor of the previous vector and not of the original one.. so should I unswap the element each time ?

Comment: I suggest you *copy* the vector, then do a swap on the copy. Note that the signature states that it is ``const``, BTW.

Comment: you mean that for each permutation I should do a copy of my vector ? Isn't that quicker to unswap the elements ?

Comment: I mean that the iterator should take the vector in the ctor, and make a copy of it. Following that, you could either unswap the copy, or just make a copy per iteration. The former is faster, but I'd profile if it's worth the bother. The most important part is *not* to modify the original vector. It would be terribly confusing, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get it, just a try.

```
 int main()
    {
        std::vector<char> vec={'b','a','c','d'};
        std::vector<int> vec_in={1,1,0,0};

        do{
             auto it =std::find(vec_in.begin(),vec_in.end(),1);
             if( *(it++) ==1)
             {
                 for(auto &x : vec)
                 {
                     std::cout<<x<<" ";
                 }
                 std::cout<<"\n";
             }

        } while(std::next_permutation(vec_in.begin(),vec_in.end()),  
                std::next_permutation(vec.begin(),vec.end()) );
    }
```